# Как осуществить скроллинг с блоками?

Tags: java, android

Вот, к примеру, есть всего 10 достаточно больших блоков с каким-либо фоном, которые не умещаются на экране. В строке по 2 таких блока. Соответственно, как сделать скроллинг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закинуть все это в `ScrollView` ?